# How to prevent form from being resized in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

How do I prevent my form from being resized? I don't want it to be maximized (which can be toggled via the property editor), but I don't want anyone to be able to drag-resize it. Am I missing something simple, or does this require a little bit of coding?

I'm using Delphi 2007.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

TForm has the property you need. Set

BorderStyle to bsSingle

so that the form doesn't appear to be sizable, and it has the added benefit of actually ***not*** being sizable. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can set the BorderStyle to bsDialog.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget about the Constraint properties of TForm, i.e. MaxHeight, MinHeight, MaxWidth, MinWidth.

Comment: Also OnCanResize, OnConstrainedResize events.

Comment: @TOndrej Thank you for that; i never even noticed them. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can set the BorderStyle to *bsSingle*, too. That will give you a proper top level frame, with icon and everything.

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to get really geeky (i.e. the answers above are better), you can intercept the RESIZE Windows message.

I would go with the Constraints property myself.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Set borderstyle to bstoolwindow. The windows will only have a close button and title bar.